# SML: Look and Say Function

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm having trouble with writing the look and say function recursively.  It's supposed to take a list of integers and evaluate to a list of integers that "reads as spoken."  For instance,

`look_and_say([1, 2, 2])` = "one one two twos" = `[1, 1, 2, 2]`

and

`look_and_say([2, 2, 2])` = "three twos" = `[3, 2]`

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to add elements to the list (and keep track of that list) throughout my recursive calls.

Here's an auxiliary function I've written that should be useful:

```
fun helper(current : int, count : int, remainingList : int list) : int list =
    if (current = hd remainingList) then
        helper(current, count + 1, tl remainingList)
    else
        (* add count number of current to list *)
        helper(hd remainingList, 1, tl remainingList);
```

And here's a rough outline for my main function:

```
fun look_and_say(x::y : int list) : int list =
    if x = nil then
    (* print *)
    else
        helper(x, 1, y);
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the input list sorted as in your two examples? If not -- you might want to run it through as sort first.

Comment: @JohnColeman not sorted as in those examples, but I'm hoping my auxiliary function takes care of that (i.e. doesn't need to be sorted for it to work properly)

Comment: but surely it is a vastly simpler problem if it is sorted

Comment: @JohnColeman mm, not sure why actually

Comment: nevermind -- I misunderstood and thought that the goal was to group the 1s together, the 2s together, etc., with the count of the number of occurrences before each distinct number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, although it doesn't look as if your helper will ever terminate. Here's a way of implementing it without a helper.

```
fun look_and_say [] = []
  | look_and_say (x::xs) =
      case look_and_say xs of
        [] => [1,x]
      | a::b::L => if x=b then (a+1)::b::L 
                   else 1::x::a::b::L
```

And here's a way of implementing it with your helper.

```
fun helper(current, count, remainingList) =
  if remainingList = [] then
    [count, current]
  else if current = hd remainingList then
    helper(current, count + 1, tl remainingList)
  else count::current::look_and_say(remainingList)
and look_and_say [] = []
  | look_and_say (x::y) = helper(x, 1, y)
```

Comment: Second one actually makes more sense to me but why is case statement "case look_and_say xs of..."...should it be "case xs of..."?  Also do you need the "and" connecting the two given that look_and_say makes use of helper but not vice versa?

Comment: It's correct, it's just a different way of attacking the problem. In the second solution, we examine each list element one by one and increment a counter if we see matching consecutive elements. In the first solution, we examine the look_and_say of the tail of the list, and if the result of that has at least two elements, then we know that the first element is a counter for the second element. This way we don't need a helper to keep track of the counter.